# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am receiving a no route matches error from the line `<%= link_to "Ask User Out", askout_user_message_path(@user), :class => "button" %>`.

This used to work before I added a gem but now it stopped working. I tried moving under collection but I get no luck with that as that's where it used to be.

Routes:

```
 resources :users do |user|

 resources :messages do
   member do
     post :new
     get 'askout', action: 'askout'
   end
 end
  collection do
     get :trashbin
     post :empty_trash

end
 end

 resources :conversations do
   member do
     post :reply
     post :trash
     post :untrash
   end
 end
```

Old Routes:

```
 resources :users do |user|

    resources :messages do
      collection do
        post 'delete_multiple'
        get 'askout', action: 'askout'
        get 'reply', action: 'reply'
      end
    end
  end
```

My routes changed as I added mailboxer gem.

Comment: This nested route is expection a message id since you defined askout in the member of the resource :messages, use the helper like this : `askout_user_message_path(@user, message)` where message is the Message found with params[:id] --- If you don't want it to need a message id, put it in the collection block and use `askout_user_messages_path(@user)` (plural on messages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd be better doing this:

```
   #config/routes.rb
   resources :users do
     resources :messages do
       member do
         post :new
         get :askout
       end
     end
     collection do
         get :trashbin
         post :empty_trash
      end
   end
```

This will give you:

```
users/1/messages/5/askout
```

---

What I think you want:

```
   #config/routes.rb
   resources :users do
     resources :messages do
       post :new
       collection do
         get :askout
       end
     end
     collection do
         get :trashbin
         post :empty_trash
      end
   end
```

This will give you:

```
users/2/messages/askout
```

The path helper will be as determined in the `rake routes` view -- you should look at it to get an idea as to what your route is called (allowing you to write it accordingly)

Comment: i was having in understanding between collection and member. It's like if i want `courses/:id/features` then it should be under member, if just `courses/features` then collection. Am i understand it right ?

Comment: collection = `courses/features`, member = `courses/:id/features`, "none" = `courses/:course_id/features`

Comment: In member = `courses/:id/features`, what kind `ID` has tobe passed. if its nested routes like in your answer.

Comment: Nested resources will automatically create a series of `member` / `collection` routes for the controller you're referencing. EG `resources :x do resources :y end` will result in `collection x/:x_id/y`. If you're manually setting a `member` route for your nested resource, you'll have to set the *`id`* for your nested record, and `:parent_id` for the parent. If you write a question, I'll write a detailed answer for you if you need

Comment: No problem! Offer still stands for the question :D

Comment: there is link about Rails routes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384313/rails-routes-nested-member-collection-namespace-scope-and-customizable