# Rails routes: Nested, Member, Collection, namespace, scope and customizable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am trying to understand more about Rails routes.

**Member and Collection**

```
  # Example resource route with options:
     resources :products do
       member do
         get 'short'
         post 'toggle'
       end

       collection do
         get 'sold'
       end
     end
```

**Namespace and Scope**

```
  # Example resource route within a namespace:
     namespace :admin do
       resources :products
     end

     scope :admin do
       resources :products
     end
```

**Constraints, Redirect_to**

```
# Example resource route with options:
 get "/questions", to: redirect {|params, req| 
     begin
       id = req.params[:category_id]
       cat = Category.find(id)
       "/abc/#{cat.slug}"
     rescue
       "/questions"
     end
 }
```

---

**Customization:**

```
resources :profiles
```

original url from `resource profiles` for edit.

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/1/edit
```

I want to make it for users available only through click `edit profile` and see url like in below.

```
http://localhost:3000/profile/edit
```

---

Also, is there advanced routing, How most big companies design their routes in rails ? I would be really glad to see new kind of routes if there exist.

Thank You !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
**Collection & Member routes**
```

> - A member route requires an ID, because it acts on a member.
> - A collection route doesn't require an ID because it acts on a
>     collection of objects

`:member` creates path with pattern `/:controller/:id/:your_method`

`:collection` creates path with the pattern `/:controller/:your_method`

`For example :`

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :abc => :get } => /users/abc
map.resources :users, :member => { :abc => :get } => /users/1/abc

**Scopes & Namespaces routes**
```

> `namespace` and `scope` in the Rails `routes` affect the controller
>   names, URIs, and named routes.
>
> *The scope method gives you fine-grained control:*

```
scope 'url_path_prefix', module: 'module_prefix', as: 'named_route_prefix' do
  resources :model_name
end
```

`For Example :`

```
scope 'foo', module: 'bar', as: 'baz' do
  resources :posts
end
```

produces routes as :

```
  Prefix Verb         URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    baz_posts GET    /foo/posts(.:format)          bar/posts#index
              POST   /foo/posts(.:format)          bar/posts#create
 new_baz_post GET    /foo/posts/new(.:format)      bar/posts#new
edit_baz_post GET    /foo/posts/:id/edit(.:format) bar/posts#edit
     baz_post GET    /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      bar/posts#show
              PATCH  /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      bar/posts#update
              PUT    /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      bar/posts#update
              DELETE /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      bar/posts#destroy
```

> The namespace method is the simple case — it prefixes everything.

```
namespace :foo do
  resources :posts
end
```

produces routes as :

```
   Prefix Verb        URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    foo_posts GET    /foo/posts(.:format)          foo/posts#index
              POST   /foo/posts(.:format)          foo/posts#create
 new_foo_post GET    /foo/posts/new(.:format)      foo/posts#new
edit_foo_post GET    /foo/posts/:id/edit(.:format) foo/posts#edit
     foo_post GET    /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      foo/posts#show
              PATCH  /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      foo/posts#update
              PUT    /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      foo/posts#update
              DELETE /foo/posts/:id(.:format)      foo/posts#destroy

**Constraints & Redirect**
```

> Rails routes are executed sequentially, you can mimic conditional
>   login in the following manner:

```
match '/route' => 'controller#action', :constraints => Model.new
match '/route' => 'user#action'
```

The first line checks whether the conditions of the constraint are met (i.e., if the request is emanating from a Model domain). If the constraint is satisfied, the request is routed to controller#action.

```
We can add constraints to routes for multiple uses like for ip-matching, params matching, restrict format parameter, request-based restrictions etc as :

- ip-matching
   => resources :model, constraints: { ip: /172\.124\.\d+\.\d+/ }
- filtering id params
   => match 'model/:id', to: 'model#show' ,constraints: { id: /\d+/}, via: :get
- restrict format params
   => match 'model/:id', to: 'model#show' ,constraints: { format: 'json' }, via: :get
- request-based constraints
   => get 'admin/', to: 'admin#show', constraints: { subdomain: 'admin' }
```

Comment: THX, another question, i have `resource :questions` but also i do have `constraints: { subdomain: 'blog' }` and  `resource :posts` under it. Now when I am going to  subdomain blog, i am still can see questions. do u block to not give access for question

Answer (score 2):

Use a singular resource for it:

```
resource :profile
```

and in controller manipulate the profile of current user.

As for complex routes - usually namespaces, nested resources with shallow routes and custom actions are all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028653/difference-between-collection-route-and-member-route-in-ruby-on-rails) answer which answers you first part of the question.

To answer second part of your question. You can treat "profile" as your singular resource (the singularity of the noun itself represents a singular resource). For a detailed description you can refer to this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).